# Ceres solver number of parameters question

Tags: c++, eigen3, ceres-solver

I write a functor like this:

```
class Functor
{
...
    static CostFunction* create()
    {
        return new AutoDiffCostFunction<Functor, N_RES, N_PARAMS>(new Functor()); 
    }
...
}
```

I call it like:

```
std::vector<double> params(N_PARAMS, 0);
CostFunction* costFunc = Functor::create();
problem.AddResidualBlock(costFunc, nullptr, params.data());
```

It's weird that this does not work when `N_PARAMS=236`, but works for other like `6`, `237`(I tried). The error message is Segement Fault.
And I used Ceres Solver before, and never met such problem.

Is there any limit for the number of parameters in Ceres Solver?

=========================================update===================
I write like this:

```
class ReprojError {
public:            
    ReprojError(
        const std::vector<std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>>& pt2d,
        const std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4>>& vmProjs) : 
        m_pt2d(pt2d), m_vmProjs(vmProjs) { }
    
    template<typename _Tp>
    bool operator () (const _Tp* const pts, _Tp* aResiduals) const 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "?" << std::endl;
            if(m_pt2d[i].empty())
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 276; ++j)
                {
                    aResiduals[i * 276 * 2 + j * 2] = _Tp(0);
                    aResiduals[i * 276 * 2 + j * 2 + 1] = _Tp(0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                auto proj = m_vmProjs[i];
                 for(int j = 0; j < 276; ++j)
                {
                    auto X = pts[j * 3];
                    auto Y = pts[j * 3 + 1];
                    auto Z = pts[j * 3 + 2];

                    auto newX = (_Tp)proj(0, 0) * X + (_Tp)proj(0, 1) * Y + (_Tp)proj(0, 2) * Z + (_Tp)proj(0, 3);
                    auto newY = (_Tp)proj(1, 0) * X + (_Tp)proj(1, 1) * Y + (_Tp)proj(1, 2) * Z + (_Tp)proj(1, 3);
                    auto newZ = (_Tp)proj(2, 0) * X + (_Tp)proj(2, 1) * Y + (_Tp)proj(2, 2) * Z + (_Tp)proj(2, 3);
                    
                    aResiduals[i * 276 * 2 + j * 2] = newX / newZ - m_pt2d[i][j](0);
                    aResiduals[i * 276 * 2 + j * 2 + 1] = newY / newZ - m_pt2d[i][j](1);
                }               
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    static ceres::CostFunction* create(
        const std::vector<std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>>& pt2d,
        const std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4>>& vmProjs) 
    {
        return (new ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<ReprojError, 24 * 2 * 276, 276 * 3>(
            new ReprojError(pt2d, vmProjs)));
    }

private:
    const std::vector<std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>>& m_pt2d;
    const std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4>>& m_vmProjs;

public:
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
};
```

and has define:

```
EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION(Eigen::Vector3d)
EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4>)
```

And '?' didn't output, which means the operator() wasn't be executed.

Comment: Don't put C tag on C++ questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such parameter limit. It would be helpful to compile the code in debug mode to see what is going on.

That said, why are you putting all this in a single costfunction, why not have a cost function for each observation?

Comment: Is there difference between these two ways to construct?

Comment: Yes, you will generate MUCH less code in a single costfunctor. The compiler will have an easier time.

Comment: also each of your costfunctions will not depend on all your parameters. It will just depend on 3 parameters at a time.

Comment: Also don't your need numparams to be a multiple of 3? 236 will cause an out of bounds access but 237 won't.